# What is dormant crypto?

Tags: cryptography

What is dormant crypto and where we can use this dormant crypto?

what is the difference between dormant crypto and normal crypto?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure cryptography

Comment: This off-topic stackoverflow question may belong on http://security.stackexchange.com/ but I couldn't find the exact flag that would flag it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "**dormant cryptography**" refers to items which, at the time of export, contain embedded cryptographic parts or components which are rendered functionally inert or inactive by design.

This dormant cryptography must be "activated" or "enabled" (typically using special components or software purchased separately) by the manufacturer before it can be used to encrypt data. Items with "dormant cryptography", and the associated commodities, software, or technology by which the cryptography is enabled, are controlled under the EAR and subject to all applicable EI, NS, and AT controls.

[Source:](http://www.bis.doc.gov/encryption/oct2kqandas.html)